Ngx-stripe or stripe.js looking for @sentry modules, but latest @sentry version doesn't have needed files, do I need @sentry?
I'm using ngx-stripe and when I mount an element I get a bunch of node errors.
It seems that the latest version of ngx-stripe or @stripe/stripe.js is looking for @sentry node modules and I don't have them installed. I might have recently removed it by accident when I upgraded node and all modules to 17. I kinda performed a brut upgrade by deleting node_modules and then installing all latest, while removing some along the way (ones I thought weren't needed!)
After looking in the @sentry repo the latest version doesn't contain any of the files throwing errors (see below). I have to go back to version 6.16.1 to get the files.
Question - Generally speaking, do I need @sentry, what is it for and why is ngx-stripe and/or @stripe/stripe.js using it? I can run the ngx-stripe component, do what I need to do and there's no issues/errors to use the component. Can I suppress these errors or will that come back to bite me in the ass later on?
Files missing:

Could not read source map for file:///Users/charles/yogabandy/client/node_modules/%40sentry/core/esm/integration.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/charles/yogabandy/client/node_modules/@sentry/core/esm/integration.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///Users/charles/yogabandy/client/node_modules/%40sentry/browser/esm/transports/base.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/charles/yogabandy/client/node_modules/@sentry/browser/esm/transports/base.js.map'


Please include your package.json and package-lock.json files at your question.

@chuckd This also bit me just now, I'm also using nxg-stripe. Did you figure it out, by any chance?

no, just installed Sentry and moved on. Will swing back to take a look another day.

Sentry is an error logger for JS client (https://sentry.io/) it allows you to know what errors appears in the console of your users, while their using your app.
Looking at ngx-stripe package.json (https://github.com/richnologies/ngx-stripe/blob/main/package.json) and stripe-js package.json (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js) none of them points to the @sentry package. Neither their package-lock. This means that those package aren't responsible for checking @sentry files. This must has been added by another package in your project.
Try to check your package-lock.json to know which package requires the usage of Sentry

Hi Antoine. What would I look for in package-lock.json? I just looked in the file and it doesn't look like there are any modules that have @sentry as a dependency. I only see references like "node_modules/@sentry/..." Is it possible something outside of package-lock is dependent on @sentry?

This sounds strange. If a package needs sentry, it should be in your package-lock.json as a dependency or subdependency. Can you host your package-lock somewhere and send it ?

what would be the quickest and easiest way to do that?

through git for example
